# How to expire cached data of memcache

Tags: drupal-7, memcached

I have installed memcache and its required package on ubuntu and enable memcache module in drupal 7. Memcache worked well but when a new node is created or updated, view should be updated but it always provide the cache version of page not updated version of page.

i want to expire memcache cache when we create or update a node.

Cache must be rebuild.

I am using these package version:

- Drupal 7.24
- Php 5.5.3
- Ubuntu 13.10.2
- Memcached 1.4.14
- Drupal memcache module 7.x

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the view isn't updated or the node isn't updated?

See if the following module is helphul: https://www.drupal.org/project/expire

Comment: Hi

Yes, my view is not updated after created or updated a node.

I have use expire module but memcache cache not clear with this module. i was clear cache on created or updated a node with expire module. 

I have used flush_all command of telnet but memcache cache was not flush.

I also use the php code for flush cache. but didn't worked

$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->addServer('localhost',11211);
$memcache_obj->flush();

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache from the drupal front end?

Comment: I am wondering if this is an issue because you have set a views cache in the view and if you are logged in, this might conflict with your expecttion

Comment: Yes, i have clear cache from the drupal front end. but memcache cache not cleard.